# Is my TFS2010 backup/restore hosed?

Tags: tfs, reporting-services, backup, restore

I recently set up a sandbox TFS to test TFS-specific features without interfering with the production TFS. I was happy I did this sooner than I thought--I hadn't been backing up the encryption key from SSRS and upon restoring the reporting databases, they remained inactive, requiring initialization that could only come from applying the encryption key. Said encryption key was lost when I nuked the partition after backing up the TFS databases.

The only option I seemed to have is to delete the encrypted data. I'm fine with this, since there wasn't much in there to begin with, however once they're deleted I'm not quite sure how to configure TFS to recognize a new installation of these services while using the restored versions of everything else. Unfortunately, the TFS help file doesn't seem to account for this state though. Is there a way to essentially rebuild the reporting and analysis databases? Or are they gone forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the TFS Admin console, have you tried going into your Reporting section underneath the Application Tier?  There is an option for "Start Rebuild", which should rebuild your warehouse, models, and reports based upon what is currently in the TFS database(s).

If that does not work, you could always try stopping the jobs, deleting the databases and then starting the jobs back up.  I *believe* that it will rebuild them from scratch at that point.  I only have my production 2010 instance up and running, and not a development rig anymore, otherwise I would test this for you.